# Unable to publish event for app developer account in Facebook API Version2 without review process

Tags: facebook

I have created a Facebook app and I want to publish event. But after upgrade of Facebook API to version 2, I understood that there is a review process to be done. But as mentioned [in the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0),
an app developer account should be able to publish events without review process. I am unable to publish event even with app developer account. It throws me following error:

> Executing a POST to https://graph.facebook.com/1440689676189017/events with parameters (sent in request body):

```
name=newEvent&start_time=2014-06-05T18:30:00+0000&end_time=2014-06-29T19:30:00+0000&description=&access_token=ACCESS_TOKE&format=json
6 Jun, 2014 11:01:37 AM com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient makeRequestAndProcessResponse
INFO: Facebook responded with HTTP status code 400 and response body: {"error":{"message":"(#12) events management API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher","type":"OAuthException","code":12}}
```

Could somebody give me an idea why this is happening even for developer account?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the error message:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#12) events management API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher","type":"OAuthException","code":12}}
```

You cannot publish events via API anymore with Graph API v20.0. It's written in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event/#publish
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Quotes:

> You cannot create events via the Graph API.

> create_event is no longer available.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 1.Can you let me know if I submit my app for review process and reviewed successfully will I be able to publish event with create_event(as we do with version 1). 2. If not can you let me know the process to publish event in version2.

Comment: What Part of "you cannot create events with Graph API V2.0" is unclear to you?

Comment: How does Eventbrite do it? Through their service I am still able to publish events to Facebook.