# C# MVC Facebook Create Event

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create Facebook event from my application and I've got (#100) Invalid parameter OAuthException.

```
string FB_Start = String.Format("{0:s}", _sTime);
                string FB_End = String.Format("{0:s}", _eTime);
ev.Add("name", Name);
            ev.Add("start_time", FB_Start);
            ev.Add("end_time", FB_End);

            ev.Add("description", Description);
            ev.Add("location", Location);
```

...

```
client.Post("/me/events", ev);
```

Whats wrong? How can I resolve this? I tried to use DateTime variable not string, but not works, tried to use DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToUniversalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) but not works i have no got idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an Event via the Graph API is no longer possible if you use the v2.0. See my answer here [Unable to publish event for app developer account in Facebook API Version2 without review process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078536/unable-to-publish-event-for-app-developer-account-in-facebook-api-version2-witho/24079642#24079642) and the linked Facebook docs.

Also, have a look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/events/#publish

Comment: Ohh. Bad news :( But thank you for the info.
And maybe do you know any other way (not with graph API or I don't know) for create facebook event from a C# MVC application ?

Comment: No. And I guess there is none, because FB is restricting this for a purpose presumeably.

Comment: And maybe can I use for this the v1.0 Graph Api ? Is that possible ?